# Phpmyadmin problema no login

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, password

Eu mudei a minha pass do `phpmyadmin` e sem querer adicionei um espaço no fim. Agora eu não consigo entrar no `phpmyadmin`.

Há algum caracter especial para representar o espaço?

Comment: Entra como usuários root e altera a senha do usuário phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

Segue esse passo a passo no seu terminal que ira resolver seu problema:

1°: Execute com sudo o mysql

```
sudo mysql
```

2°: Depois altere a senha do root

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'digitesuasenha';
```

3°: Depois de todos previlégios

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Depois tente logar no phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Você pode inserir a senha manualmente com o espaço no arquivo de configuração 'my.cnf' dentro de aspas duplas, para que assim possa identificar quando há o inicio da senha e quando ela finaliza, assim você terá o acesso ao phpmyadmin novamente e poderá troca-lá depois de logado.